# InitializeComponent takes too much time initializing ListView control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have built a simple application, doesn't do much, just reads from and saves to a simple text file, when i try to debug/run it, it takes too much time to load (14 seconds),just to draw a listview from the designer.cs, the controls are simply made, the listview is empty and has only 3 columns, my laptop is quite powerful (6700HQ i7). [image: SlowDown]

The code line is `this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();`, my target framework is 4.5.2, and the target cpu is set to "any CPU".

Comment: 14 seconds is bizarre, no CPU load either.  This has to be an environmental problem, maybe the disk drive is having problems.  You can see more by enabling unmanaged debugging and hitting Debug > Break All when the delay occurs.

Comment: @HansPassant i only have "Enable native debugging" and checking it and debugging doesn't show me much.

Comment: Well, it is too late now that you rebooted.  Questions like this *really* need to document the installed anti-malware product, we can only avoid the crapware when we know what is troublesome.

Comment: That is true, but after deleting the listview and replacing it with another, i realized it hangs in the line code right after `System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));`, any idea ?

Comment: You are giving us misleading info.  Show us a good stack trace.

Comment: What misleading info, when i restarted the computer, it worked, it loaded in less than 1 sec, when i closed and started the exe itself, it hanged again, so i loaded VS and tried debuging, it's getting stuck at the listview line, i decided to delete the listview and make another one, so the designer.cs got regenerated, now it hangs on the textbox, the only thing in common for these two controls, is that the line code is situated right after the one i put in my last comment. I'll post the call stack if you want it but i don't think it'll give you anything useful (http://i.imgur.com/VA8j6WL.png)